# Statistical Test for seeing differences in a single sample

Tags: descriptive-statistics

So I've been trying to analyze 3 repeats for some data (essentially, a single independent variable measured at three different times), which would look like something like this:

Test 1 
[Value]
Test 2
[Value]
Test 3
[Value]

Now, I want to see if these values are different from one another, but I don't exactly know how to do that when each test only had a single data point taken (no ANOVA). Is there a statistical test to determine if these values are different, without having a known mean?

Comment: When you say "these values are different from one another" my immediate reaction is: "Is the units place the same? Is the tens place the same? Is the tenths place the same? etc." Since this is presumably not what you are asking, it would be nice for people like me if you could clarify what you're looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately, not always - sometimes the data is something like:

7.967261, 8.032799, 7.7836

Answer (score 0):

You can use repeated-measures ANOVA, or alternatively the Friedman test, which is its nonparametric equivalent.

Comment: To use repeated-measures ANOVA, though, wouldn't I need multiple values for each test for variance? I've never used the Friedman test so I'll look into it.